# Existence of polytope

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, geometry, polytopes

Does there exist a polytope in dimensional d consisting of $k>d+1$ faces satisfying that every d faces intersect? I tried 3 dimensional cases, and it seems negative. But is it all negative for any dimension $d\geq 2$?

Comment: This is indeed not possible, since the polar of such a polytope would be $d$-neighbourly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighborly_polytope

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is it because the dual of such polytope can only be a simplex($d$-neighbourly), so the polytope itself is also a simplex?

Comment: yes, that's exactly it!

Comment: What if the original polytope is not convex? Does the argument still go through? Or the polytope must be convex given that every d faces intersect?